# Query iPhone contacts with Java program

Tags: java, iphone, bluetooth

I want to query and write the contacts of an iPhone via bluetooth out of my java program. Is that possible? Are there any good bluetooth libraries for java that also support the appropriate bluetooth profiles? Any experiences?

Answer (score 1):

After searching and testing for a while: It is possible. I've used the bluecove library. I now can query the phonebook from an iPhone. Unfortunately I have to pair the iphone in advance.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is definitely not possible.

Comment: Why? Please explain or give sources.

Comment: I've just tried the bluetooth library "bluecove". With this library I find the services on a Samsung Galaxy S3, but it does not work with iPhone 3GS.